# Storing function metadata

Tags: c++, c++17

In a project, we have a file that contains something like a script which we need to parse. At the moment the validation is tough since we have an array of functions returing `variable` and taking `variableList` (basically `std::variant<>`and vector of variants, see definition below)
I am trying to have function metadata available (number of input arguments and its type, possibly return value type for validating the input "script". I would like to replace `std::function` with something like this:

```
using variable = std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string>;
using variableList = std::vector<variable>;

enum {
    BOOL_TYPE = 0,
    INT_TYPE = 1,
    DOUBLE_TYPE = 2,
    STRING_TYPE = 3,

    VARIABLE_BOOL_TYPE = 0 | 0x80,
    VARIABLE_INT_TYPE = 1 | 0x80,
    VARIABLE_DOUBLE_TYPE = 2 | 0x80,
    VARIABLE_STRING_TYPE = 3 | 0x80
};

struct Function
{
    std::string                                 fname;
    std::vector<int>                            indexes;
    std::function<variable(variableList &&)>    fn;

    variable operator()(variableList && list)
    {
        if (indexes.size() != list.size() &&
            (indexes.size() == 0 || (indexes[0] & 0x80) != 0x80))
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid number of arguments" << std::endl;
            return variable(0);
        }


        int idx = 0;
        for (auto i : list)
        {
            if ((indexes[0] & 0x80) ? i.index() != (indexes[0] & 0x03), idx++ : i.index() != indexes[idx++])
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid argument type" << std::endl;
                return variable(0);
            }
        }

        return fn(std::forward<decltype(list)>(list));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Function f = { "fName", {BOOL_TYPE, INT_TYPE, BOOL_TYPE}, [](variableList && list) -> variable {
        for (auto i : list)
        {
            std::visit([](auto && val) -> void {
                std::cout << val << std::endl;
            }, i);
        }
        return variable(0);
    }};

    auto arguments = {variable(true),variable(true),variable(true)};
    auto returnValue = f(arguments);
}
```

The project supports c++17. Any modifications, suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**: Initially I wanted to use templates instead of `indices` and enum, but I wasn't quite successful with creating array of Function class with different template arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer `enum class` with a name, and probably rename the enums, e.g. `BOOL_TYPE` becomes `TYPE::BOOL` or however you'd like to do the naming. Why do you want them to be an unnamed enum type?

---

You're printing an error to cout when there's an error. At the very least, print to cerr, so that someone running this might be able to filter output if they'd like to. I would personally either return a `variant<variable, error_message_type>` or throw an exception if there's an error like that though. Otherwise errors could easily slip through unnoticed.

---

This validation loop is inefficient and confusing.

Prefer extracting the conditional if possible. It appears to be ensuring that all the types are the same if it is a "VARIABLE_" type. Perhaps "variadic" may be more appropriate?

```
    int idx = 0;
    for (auto i : list)
    {
        if ((indexes[0] & 0x80) ? i.index() != (indexes[0] & 0x03), idx++ : i.index() != indexes[idx++])
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid argument type" << std::endl;
            return variable(0);
        }
    }
```

---

`indexes` could take a type enum instead of `int` if it had a name. Why is it called indexes? You may be able to leverage more of `std::variant` and possibly not need the enum at all.

---

`for (auto i : list)` You probably want `auto & i`, since this will result in string copies in the case of string variants.

---

`return fn(std::forward<decltype(list)>(list));`
This is unnecessary. std::forward is useful for templated types, but you know the type of list, it's a `variableList &&`.

You could move the list, but I'm not sure that's what you really want.

Comment: I totally agree with all the above, but I didn't want this question to be about such things but rather how to store that information in a more viable manner. - Something like `std::tuple` with checks whether an array of variants have the same type as std::tuple variadic parameters in that order

Comment: A tuple of types as the signature would require the Function class to be templated (and heterogenous). It could work but it would need to inherit from some base class if you wanted to store them in a container, and it would generate a new set of validation code per function signature. Otherwise a list of enums is fine, you could loop over them and `switch` on the enum value, testing the argument type using `std::holds_alternative`

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this?

Add script functions to a function map like this:

```
function_map["function name"] =
      MakeScriptFunction<ReturnType, ArgumentTypes...>(fn);
```

call them like this:

```
//                  |arg 0       |arg 1|arg 2| arg 3|
function_map["foo"]({"foo string", 69.0,  666, false});

// or like this
function_map["foo"](variable_list);
```

---

Demo that shows off construction, calling, and what happens if wrong argument numbers or types are provided. Note that you can do a non-exception implementation using `sizeof...(ArgumentTypes)` and `std::holds_alternative`.
https://godbolt.org/z/sdgMra

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>

using Variable = std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string>;
using VariableList = std::vector<Variable>;
using ScriptFunction = std::function<Variable(VariableList const&)>;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes,
          typename FunctionType = std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes&&...)>>
ScriptFunction MakeScriptFunction(FunctionType&& function) {
  return [function = std::move(function)](VariableList const& argument_list) {
    auto argument_iter = argument_list.rbegin();
    return function(std::get<ArgumentTypes>(*argument_iter++)...);
  };
}

int main() {
  auto function_map = std::unordered_map<std::string, ScriptFunction>{};

  function_map["foo"] = MakeScriptFunction<int, std::string, double, int, bool>(
      [](auto& s, auto d, auto i, auto b) {
        std::cout << "inside foo, s=" << s << " d=" << d << " i=" << i
                  << " b=" << b << std::endl;
        return 420;
      });
  function_map["bar"] =
      MakeScriptFunction<std::string>([]() { return "barbarbar"; });

  // bad definition (mismatch of function and declared types) causes compile
  // error error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda()>) (const int&)' 16 |
  // return function(std::get<ArgumentTypes>(*argument_iter++)...);
  //   function_map["bad definition"] =
  //       MakeScriptFunction<std::string, int>([]() { return "barbarbar"; });

  // inline call
  function_map["foo"]({"foo string", 69.0, 666, false});

  // l value call
  auto foo_args = VariableList{"foo string", 69.0, 666, false};
  function_map["foo"](foo_args);

  // print out return value of a function
  std::visit([](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << std::endl; },
             (function_map["bar"])({}));

  // wrong order
  try {
    function_map["foo"]({"foo string", 69.0, false, 666});
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  // wrong number of args
  try {
    function_map["foo"]({"foo string", 69.0, 666});
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this has a bug if too many parameters are supplied but can be addressed with size...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
inline std::enable_if_t<N == 0, bool> typeCheck(variableList& list) noexcept
{
    if (false == std::holds_alternative<std::tuple_element_t<N, T>>(list[N]))
    {
        std::cout << "Function type check failed for " << N << ". element." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Expected: " << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<N, T>).name() << "; Got: " <<
            std::visit([](auto&& t) -> std::string { return typeid(decltype(t)).name(); }, list[N]) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
inline std::enable_if_t<0 < N, bool> typeCheck(variableList& list) noexcept
{
    if (false == std::holds_alternative<std::tuple_element_t<N, T>>(list[N]))
    {
        std::cout << "Function type check failed for " << N << ". element." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Expected: " << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<N, T>).name() << "; Got: " <<
            std::visit([](auto&& t) -> std::string { return typeid(decltype(t)).name(); }, list[N]) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return typeCheck<N-1, T>(list);
}

struct Function
{
    virtual std::size_t numArguments() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual bool checkVariables(variableList& list) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual variable operator()(variableList& list) = 0;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct FunctionImpl : Function
{
    using pack = std::tuple<Ts...>;

    FunctionImpl(std::function<variable(Ts && ...args)>&& fn) : Function{}, fn(std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn)) {}

    variable operator()(variableList& list)
    {
        return std::apply(fn, vectorToTuple<std::tuple_size_v<pack>>(list));
    }

    std::size_t numArguments() const noexcept
    {
        return std::tuple_size_v<pack>;
    }
    bool checkVariables(variableList& list) const noexcept
    {
        if (list.size() < std::tuple_size_v<pack>)
        {
            std::cout << "Bad number of arguments" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        return typeCheck<std::tuple_size_v<pack> -1, pack>(list);
    }

private:
    std::function<variable(Ts && ...args)> fn;

    template <typename T, typename std::size_t... Indices>
    auto vectorToTupleHelper(const std::vector<T>& v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<std::tuple_element_t<Indices, pack>>(v[Indices])...);
    }

    template <std::size_t N, typename T>
    auto vectorToTuple(const std::vector<T>& v) {
        return vectorToTupleHelper(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }
};

#include <memory>
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Function>, 2> fnArray = {
    std::make_unique<FunctionImpl<bool,int>> ([](bool,int) -> variable {
        return variable(0);
    }),
    std::make_unique<FunctionImpl<int, double, bool>> ([](int a, short b, bool c) -> variable {
        std::cout << "    a: " << a << std::endl
            << "    b: " << b << std::endl
            << "    c: " << c << std::endl;
        return variable(12);
    })
};

int main()
{
    variableList list = { variable(2), variable(2.2), variable(false) };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << fnArray[0]->checkVariables(list) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << fnArray[1]->checkVariables(list) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Calling 2:" << std::endl;
    auto result = fnArray[1]->operator()(list);
    std::cout << "    result: " << std::get<int>(result) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `list.size() < std::tuple_size_v<pack>` Why not do an equality comparison? It's possible that this will accidentally work, i.e. an unintended extra argument wouldn't cause an error where you would want it to.

Comment: Oh, yea sure, ty nice catch

Comment: I don't think the T parameter is needed in `vectorToTuple`. Also you could use a templated lambda so you don't need a helper function. Templated lambdas are only in gcc right now though I think.

Answer (score 0):

## Fix the warnings

```
235745.cpp: In member function ‘variable Function::operator()(variableList&&)’:
235745.cpp:43:49: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   43 |             if ((indexes[0] & 0x80) ? i.index() != (indexes[0] & 0x03), idx++ : i.index() != indexes[idx++])
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
235745.cpp:43:91: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type’ {aka ‘int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   43 |             if ((indexes[0] & 0x80) ? i.index() != (indexes[0] & 0x03), idx++ : i.index() != indexes[idx++])
```

It looks like the first of those is reporting a serious error; perhaps that line was supposed to be:

```
        if ((indexes[0] & 0x80) ? ++idx, i.index() != (indexes[0] & 0x03) : i.index() != indexes[idx++])
```

Or just start `idx` at -1, and increment it immediately before the `if` instead.

## Magic numbers

There's a sprinkling of `0x80` and `0x3` around the code with no explanation.  I'd expect those to be named constants.

## Default promotions and default arguments.

This seems much more restrictive than standard function calls, where (for example) `int` arguments can be promoted for functions expecting `double`.  Is that intentional?  It's certainly surprising.

Similarly, it's disappointing that we can't use default arguments as we can in ordinary C++ functions.

## Formatting

Please don't do this - it's really hard to read:

> ```
> std::string                                 fname;
> std::vector<int>                            indexes;
> std::function<variable(variableList &&)>    fn;
> ```